# GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.files.insert failed with Internal Error

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, spreadsheet

I have the following code where I take the data from an ods file and convert and create that file to google sheets format in another folder

```
var ssOrige = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId)
var ssOrigeBlob = ssOrige.getBlob()
var ssName = ssOrige.getName()

var newFile = {
    title : ssName,
    parents: [{id: folderDestinationId}]
  }


var ssDestination = Drive.Files.insert(newFile, ssOrigeBlob, {convert: true})
```

I get the following error

> GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to Drive.files.insert failed with Internal Error

The Drive API is active in this script

This usually happens when the file has many lines.

Sometimes the conversion is done correctly, but after many errors like this

I am accepting suggestions to convert an ods file to a spreadsheet in google format

Comment: @Marios No, I'm just taking one file and trying to convert

Comment: What is the size of the blob file in use?

Comment: @contributorpw the original file is 2 mb

Comment: Have you tried with another .ods file? Do you observe the same behavior? [Here](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603) you can find the current limitations of spreadsheet dimensions (row,columns), when converting to Google Sheets.

Comment: @Alessandro My ods files are within the limits of google spreadsheets, however it happens only when the files have many lines, like more than 20,000 lines

Comment: Can you give an example? How many lines has the file that produced the error with the above script?

Answer (score 0):

Drive.Files.insert() relies to making use of the Drive API (V2) in Advanced Google Services
Therefore, enable Drive API as an advanced Google Service.
Goto the menu item: Resources > Advanced Google Services > Drive API.
V3 throws the same error for me, but with V2 it runs.